# How to correctly push a page in the navigator after a period of time

Tags: flutter, dart, timer

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'login_page.dart';

class RegistrationCompleated extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegistrationCompleated({super.key});

  @override
  State<RegistrationCompleated> createState() => _RegistrationCompleatedState();
}

class _RegistrationCompleatedState extends State<RegistrationCompleated> {
  bool _move = false;
  int _remainingTime = 3;
  late Timer _timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _startTimer();

    super.initState();
  }

  void _startTimer() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        if (_remainingTime > 0) {
          _remainingTime--;
        } else {
          _timer.cancel();
          _move = true;
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_move == true) {
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
    }
    return WillPopScope(
      // It will prevent the page from being popped by the system
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: const Center(
            child: Text('Registration Finished'),
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(
            'The registration was successful!!!\n You will be soon redirected to the login page.\n'
            'Please insert the new credentials in the login page to sign in.\n'
            'You will be redirect to the login page in $_remainingTime',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This code does what I wish it would do, but the navigation stop working after the redirection in the loginPage. I beleive the error is due to my bad handling of timer. I would like to solve this issue with as less change as possible. I am also not familiar with dart and Flutter. I am studying them, so if you can add a little explanation I will appreciate it.

```
I/flutter ( 6029): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 6029): The following assertion was thrown building RegistrationCompleated(dirty, state:
I/flutter ( 6029): _RegistrationCompleatedState#93bd2):
I/flutter ( 6029): setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
I/flutter ( 6029): This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the
I/flutter ( 6029): process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase
I/flutter ( 6029): only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework
I/flutter ( 6029): builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built.
I/flutter ( 6029): Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
I/flutter ( 6029): The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
I/flutter ( 6029):   Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey<OverlayState>#4e841]
I/flutter ( 6029): The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
I/flutter ( 6029):   RegistrationCompleated
I/flutter ( 6029): 
I/flutter ( 6029): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 6029):   RegistrationCompleated
I/flutter ( 6029):   RegistrationCompleated:file:///C:/flutterApp/login_page/lib/registration_page.dart:18:41
I/flutter ( 6029): 
I/flutter ( 6029): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 6029): #0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4651:9)
I/flutter ( 6029): #1      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4663:6)
I/flutter ( 6029): #2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1159:15)
I/flutter ( 6029): #3      OverlayState.rearrange (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:640:5)
I/flutter ( 6029): #4      NavigatorState._flushHistoryUpdates (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4067:16)
I/flutter ( 6029): #5      NavigatorState._pushEntry (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4540:5)
I/flutter ( 6029): #6      NavigatorState.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4489:5)
I/flutter ( 6029): #7      Navigator.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2100:34)
I/flutter ( 6029): #8      _RegistrationCompleatedState.build (package:login_page/registration_compleated_page.dart:40:17)
I/flutter ( 6029): #9      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5198:27)
I/flutter ( 6029): #10     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5086:15)
I/flutter ( 6029): #11     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
I/flutter ( 6029): #12     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
I/flutter ( 6029): #13     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2780:19)
I/flutter ( 6029): #14     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:903:21)
I/flutter ( 6029): #15     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:358:5)
I/flutter ( 6029): #16     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1289:15)
I/flutter ( 6029): #17     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1219:9)
I/flutter ( 6029): #18     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1077:5)
I/flutter ( 6029): #19     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:142:13)
I/flutter ( 6029): #20     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:359:5)
I/flutter ( 6029): #21     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:112:31)
I/flutter ( 6029): 
I/flutter ( 6029): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
E/flutter ( 6029): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 2928 pos 18: '!navigator._debugLocked': is not true.
E/flutter ( 6029): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
E/flutter ( 6029): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
E/flutter ( 6029): #2      _RouteEntry.handlePush.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2928:18)
E/flutter ( 6029): #3      TickerFuture.whenCompleteOrCancel.thunk (package:flutter/src/scheduler/ticker.dart:420:15)
E/flutter ( 6029): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6029): #4      TickerFuture.whenCompleteOrCancel.thunk (package:flutter/src/scheduler/ticker.dart:419:5)
E/flutter ( 6029): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6029): 
I/flutter ( 6029): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 4532 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.
I/chatty  ( 6029): uid=10124(com.example.login_page) 1.ui identical 6 lines
I/flutter ( 6029): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 4532 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.



PS C:\flutterApp\login_page> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 3.10.0-12.0.pre.26, on Microsoft Windows [Versione 10.0.19045.2846], locale it-IT)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.5.4)
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.77.3)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove your timer, and set future.delay in your initState method. It will navigate to next page after 2 seconds ( you can change the Duration value if you need).

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () async {
        Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
      });
    });
  }
```